# Cannot create project from folder because it is already in the workspace

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I created a `Spring` project with `SpringToolSuite` from a SVN project. It worked successfully. Now I deleted the `project` without deleting the content on disk. I want to create a `project` from the folder of the previously deleted project but I could not create it : there is a message stating that a project of the same name already exists in the workspace. So how to fix that ?

Comment: Easiest is probably to find the folder in your workspace on disk and delete it. Then try to import again. Alternatively, instead of importing the project using SVN tools, use the "Import >> Existing Project(s)" wizard. Find the project on disk, point wizard at it and import it back into the workspace.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know about SPringToolSuite, I work with Visual Studio. There, if you remove your project from the solution happens the same, it kept on the hard drive just disappears from the solution explorer.

If you want to reopen it, you can just open the project file or add it back to your solution.

If you want to create another project with the same name at the same location, you have to manually delete or move the folder of your old excluded project.

Depending on your use case, you can try to do something similar.

I hope this helps.